# Warning - anonymous subclass(?) has no serial version UID

Tags: java, warnings

I have a quite weird warning while building our project.
The statement is lack of `serialVersionUID` but in fact the class in question does define such.

Can someone explain the below error?

```
[WARNING] /build/location/com/our/company/package/SomeClass.java:[178,56] [serial] serializable class <anonymous com.our.company.package.SomeClass$1> has no definition of serialVersionUID
```

I am not sure what `SomeClass$1` means in this case.

Comment: There is no error here, only a warning.

Comment: Well it's an anonymous class... so presumably your *named* class provides a serialVersionUID, but the anonymous subclass doesn't. So somewhere you've got `new SomeClass() { ... }`.

Comment: Also, `SomeClass$1` is just the name of the anonymous class - all classes have names in bytecode, and the compiler generates them for anonymous classes (from the name of the enclosing class, a $, and a number).

Comment: A simular question has been asked here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823477/warning-serial-serializable-class-someclass-has-no-definition-of-serialversio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SomeClass$1` is the first anonymous class contained in `SomeClass`. So somewhere in the code for `SomeClass`, you're using an [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html), e.g:

```
SomeType instance = new SomeType {
    public ReturnType someMethod() {
        // ...implementation...
    }
};
```

The warning is that the resulting anonymous class has no `serialVersionUID`, which could lead to serializaton problems. (I guess the base class of your anonymous class must be `serializable`.)

You can give it one:

```
SomeType instance = new SomeType {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 12345678L; // Change number as appropriate

    public ReturnType someMethod() {
        // ...implementation...
    }
};
```

...although there's some debate ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17805016/157247), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15477514/157247)) about whether having serializable nested classes is best practice.