# class of a generic collection at runtime with serialVersionUID?

Tags: java

Is this the only way to get the class of a generic collection at runtime?

```
Class<T> clazz = new HashSet<Task>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 8252429191034335636L;
        }.getClass()
```

My IDE says:

"The serializable class  does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long"

Comment: may be for part of question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477169/java-should-serializable-inner-anonymous-classes-have-serialversionuid

Comment: Your question is not clear in terms of what you're trying to achieve.  Serialization and type erasure are not strictly related.

The reason you can get (some) data about the generic parameter is because you created a (anonymous) subclass, not because of serialization.

Comment: okay, as suggested, I leave the serialVersionUID within my inner class.

Comment: @Iscoughlin I only want to get the class of a generic collection at runtime. So I cannot find an easier way to do..or is there a better way (independent of serialization)?

Comment: Why don't you just use a regular `HashSet` (that is serializable)

Comment: Note that when you serialize an instance of an inner class, the outer class instance will also be serialized. Does your outer class also have a `serialVersionUID`?

Comment: @MauricePerry I need the "type information" (Task.class) of the hashSet.

Comment: @MauricePerry no the outer class has no serializable..I guess, I will delete the serializable field of my inner class..it works withouth..I dont know why I need it..

Comment: @nimo23 what do you mean by "type information"? the generic type? you're not going to obtain it this way.

Comment: @MauricePerry sure, `new HashSet<Task>() {}.getClass()` returns the needed class information. Any other way?

Comment: @nimo23 you could, for instance, declare a static field of type `HashSet<Task>` (no instanciation needed), and then get the genericType of that field.

Comment: I tried with `private static Set<Task> test; test.getClass();`. However, does not work as returned runtime type information is not the same as with `new HashSet<Task>() {}.getClass()`.

Comment: @nimo23 I posted an answer for that particular point (so that it is correctly formatted)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with serialization, but:

```
private static Set<Task> myField;

...

        Field field = MyClass.class.getDeclaredField("myField");
        Type type = field.getGenericType();
        ParameterizedType ptype = (ParameterizedType)type;
        Type[] argTypes = ptype.getActualTypeArguments();
        Type atype = argTypes[0];
        System.out.println(atype.getTypeName());
```

Comment: I cannot replace `new HashSet<Task>() {}.getClass()` by `field.getGenericType()` for my purpose because I need the `Class<T> clazz` and not the `Type`. So I have to use `new`..

Comment: @nimo23 no you don't

Comment: I need the `Class<T>clazz` to call `clazz.getGenericSuperclass()`. Which one of the methods above returns this?